# Asking for the prod url for subscritiption based payment in phonepe payment integration

Tags: javascript, integration, payment-gateway, subscription, phonepe

My test application is working prefectly fine but in going through with production my console showing the error: "api mapping not found", i think it is due to wrong prod_URL.
Anybody to find me the url.

my application code:

I am using this url:https://api.phonepe.com/apis/hermes/pg/v3/recurring/subscription/create

docs for better reference:https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/how-to-go-live-4/

I am expecting the url which will be working fine for production

```
const payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    const payloadMain = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
    const keyIndex = 1;
    const string = payloadMain + `/v3/recurring/subscription/create` + salt_key;
    const sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(string).digest('hex');
    const checksum = sha256 + '###' + keyIndex;
    const prod_URL = 'https://api.phonepe.com/apis/hermes/pg/v3/recurring/subscription/create';
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: prod_URL,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-VERIFY': checksum,
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        request: payloadMain,
      }),
```

Comment: "i think it is due to wrong prod_URL".  Why?

Comment: Because application is working fine in the testing  one.

Answer (score 0):

If any one searching for the right url then this it:

```
const prod_URL='https://mercury-t2.phonepe.com/v3/recurring/subscription/create';
```